# DLR DefaultBinder available for use in Silverlight?

Tags: .net, dynamic-language-runtime

I'd like to use the Codeplex DefaultBinder from within a Silverlight-deployed DLR project (my own custom language implementation).

Is that possible? Is the DefaultBinder compatible with Silverlight 3 and/or 4?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that it doesn't work, because MS.Dynamic and MS.Scripting are not "core" CLR assemblies and therefore SL will consider them security-transparent (and therefore not able to perform security-privileged operations, like the various reflection gymnastics done by DefaultBinder).

It would be super helpful to use DefaultBinder in Silverlight, else it's kind of hard to do non-trivial binding to CLR code from Silverlight-based DLR solutions.